# Devise logged in user persisting to other accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I'm running into a problem with devise on rails 3.2

On heroku, I'll have somebody (X) log in using their twitter account, which works fine and authenticates them. User's are restricted from certain pages if they aren't logged in via twitter. My problem then, is that once X logs in, another person Y, using a different computer and without logging in via twitter, will access those pages and be already logged in as X automatically. Any ideas why this would happen? I'm not sure which code to post but here is the method in the controller for the page.

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def show
    @donater = Donater.find(params[:id])
    twitter_id_str = current_user.authentications.find_by_provider(:twitter).uid
    @current_user_twitter_handle = get_twitter_handle_from_id(twitter_id_str.to_i).screen_name
end
```

Comment: I just tested my app for this and with a rails 3.2 app using devise and running on Heroku.  I'm experiencing the same thing, I also had trouble sending Heroku commands from the console just now, but that just resolved itself.

Comment: I think I figured out my problem, maybe yours is similar. I am authenticating the user, but then I am getting models from information  in the url. So if you are logged in you can send a request from any url and get that info. That is bad design on my part. I am modifying my app to only search for models through associations with the currently logged in user. I'll let you know if that works for me.

Comment: That fixed it for me. I am going to post an answer in case someone else has trouble with the same thing. @PatMarx, if this doesn't fix it for you, you might want to post more of your code, like which controller you are in, and that controllers model file, and maybe even your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to only be able to find the `Donater` model associated with the user's account, you need to retrieve that `Donater` model through the currently logged in user's account.

Here is your code:

```
def show
    @donater = Donater.find(params[:id])
    twitter_id_str = current_user.authentications.find_by_provider(:twitter).uid
    @current_user_twitter_handle = get_twitter_handle_from_id(twitter_id_str.to_i).screen_name
end
```

You are checking to see if the user is logged in, but then you are just grabbing the information from the url and providing whatever `Donater` model you find. This allows anyone who is signed in to access any `Donater` model.

Hopefully you have an association set up between the `User` and `Donater`.  Then you can change your code to this:

```
def show
    @donater = Donater.find(params[:id]).where(user_id: current_user.id) # modify for your specific situation
    if @donater.empty?
      render text: "Not Found or Access Denied" # replace this with a redirect or whatever based on your needs
      return
    end
    twitter_id_str = current_user.authentications.find_by_provider(:twitter).uid
    @current_user_twitter_handle = get_twitter_handle_from_id(twitter_id_str.to_i).screen_name
end
```

Comment: I believe my original problem originates from the `current_user` method returning or persisting being set as X, the first authenticated user. That said, the solution is coincidentally very helpful for another problem I have, so thank you for that!

Comment: I'll see if I can assess what other code would be useful and make an edit to add it.

Comment: Well, I messed up the code a little, the `unless` should be an `if`. Derp. It's fixed now.